# iPhone/iPad C++ Example

Tags: c++, iphone

Does anyone know where or how to obtain a C++ example to create iPhone apps? What I am looking for is just using C++ (no objective-C or just the bare essential objective-C) and no interface builder, source only.

Can ayone help me locate such a beast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download Carmack's source for Wolfenstein3D for the iphone to see what a program that only uses the minimum of Objective-C necessary to run looks like.
He uses C mixed with Objective-C in this case ,but as everyone has mentioned, there's no way to avoid using some Objective-C if you plan on linking against the iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 3):

You can use C++ and objective-c together, there are some docs in Apple's developer guides. You just need to change the file extensions over from .m to .mm.

You still need to be a registered iPhone developer with Apple to do this however, as you need the SDK to link against.

Comment: The `.h` can stay being `.h`. It's just the `.m` needs to become `.mm`.

Comment: With more emphasis: `.hh` is plain wrong.

Comment: Whoops, should've actually looked at the docs.